# using php preg_match to get text after @something

Tags: php, regex

I'm using

```
if (preg_match('/@type\s+([^\s]+)/', $refProp->getDocComment(), $matches)) {
    return $matches[1];
} else {
     return false;
}
```

to read a datatype like:

```
/**
*@type INT
*/
```

Here, I'll get the 'INT' string.

Now, I'll like to access the hole thing. Like:

```
/**
*@type INT NOT NULL DEFAUTL 1
*/
```

Including the whitespaces. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
/@type\s+(.+?)\s?$/m
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you. Take a look at the use I'm giving it: http://flexmap.com.ar/